# Single-instance WPF application

Tags: c#, singleton, wpf

This is the code I implemented so far to create a single instance WPF application:

```
#region Using Directives
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
#endregion

namespace MyWPF
{
    public partial class MainApplication : Application, IDisposable
    {
        #region Members
        private Int32 m_Message;
        private Mutex m_Mutex;
        #endregion

        #region Methods: Functions
        private IntPtr HandleMessages(IntPtr handle, Int32 message, IntPtr wParameter, IntPtr lParameter, ref Boolean handled)
        {
            if (message == m_Message)
            {
                if (MainWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
                    MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

                Boolean topmost = MainWindow.Topmost;

                MainWindow.Topmost = true;
                MainWindow.Topmost = topmost;
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        private void Dispose(Boolean disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (m_Mutex != null))
            {
                m_Mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                m_Mutex.Close();
                m_Mutex = null;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods: Overrides
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            Boolean mutexCreated;
            String mutexName = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Local\\{{{0}}}{{{1}}}", assembly.GetType().GUID, assembly.GetName().Name);

            m_Mutex = new Mutex(true, mutexName, out mutexCreated);
            m_Message = NativeMethods.RegisterWindowMessage(mutexName);

            if (!mutexCreated)
            {
                m_Mutex = null;

                NativeMethods.PostMessage(NativeMethods.HWND_BROADCAST, m_Message, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

                Current.Shutdown();

                return;
            }

            base.OnStartup(e);

            MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
            MainWindow = window;
            window.Show(); 

            HwndSource.FromHwnd((new WindowInteropHelper(window)).Handle).AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(HandleMessages));
        }

        protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispose();
            base.OnExit(e);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly... but I have some doubts about it and I would like to receive your suggestions about how my approach could be improved.

1. I was asked by Code Analysis to implement `IDisposable` interface because I was using `IDisposable` members (the `Mutex`). Is my `Dispose()` implementation good enough? Should I avoid it because it's never going to be called?
2. It's better to use `m_Mutex = new Mutex(true, mutexName, out mutexCreated);` and check for the result or to use `m_Mutex = new Mutex(false, mutexName);` and then check for `m_Mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, false);` ? In case of multithreading I mean...
3. `RegisterWindowMessage` API call should return `UInt32`... but `HwndSourceHook` is only accepting `Int32` as message value... should I be worried about unexpected behaviors (like a result bigger than `Int32.MaxValue`)?
4. In `OnStartup` override... should I execute `base.OnStartup(e);` even if another instance is already running and I'm going to shutdown the application?
5. Is there a better way to bring the existing instance to the top that doesn't need to set `Topmost` value? Maybe `Activate()`?
6. Can you see any flaw in my approach? Something concerning multithreading, bad exceptions handling and something like that? For example... what happens if my application crashes between `OnStartup` and `OnExit`?

Answer (score 33):

This might be against the spirit of Code Review, but you don't need to write your own single instance manager for WPF! [Microsoft has already written code to accomplish this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/05/28/wpf-single-instance-application.aspx), but it has been poorly advertised.

Microsoft's single instance manager is extremely comprehensive, and I have yet to find any issues with it. (And if you don't want to use it, it can at least be a good reference for your own implementation.)

## How to manage single instances in WPF

**Step 1:** Add the `System.Runtime.Remoting` reference to your project.

**Step 2:** Add [this single instance class](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/SingleInstance.cs.txt) to your project.

**Step 3:** Implement the `ISingleInstanceApp` interface in your main application class in `App.xaml.cs` (this interface is provided by the `SingleInstance.cs` file).

For example:

`public partial class App : Application, ISingleInstanceApp`

**Step 4:** Change your startup object by going to `Project` --> `<projectname> Properties` in Visual Studio, clicking the `Application` tab. Locate `Startup object:` and select the `<projectname>.App` option.

[image: Setting WPF startup object]

**Step 5:** Define a `Main` method in `App.xaml.cs`, and give it a unique string in the `Unique` variable.

```
// TODO: Make this unique!
private const string Unique = "Change this to something that uniquely identifies your program.";

[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{   
    if (SingleInstance<App>.InitializeAsFirstInstance(Unique))
    {
        var application = new App();
        application.InitializeComponent();
        application.Run();

        // Allow single instance code to perform cleanup operations
        SingleInstance<App>.Cleanup();
    }
}

#region ISingleInstanceApp Members
public bool SignalExternalCommandLineArgs(IList<string> args)
{
    // Handle command line arguments of second instance
    return true;
}
#endregion
```

**Step 6:** Right-click on `App.xaml` in the Solution Explorer, select `Properties`, and change the Build Action to `Page`.

## Single Instance techniques

### Do nothing when new instance is opened

If you don't want anything to happen when a single instance is launched, you don't need to modify the sample code above.

### Activate original window when new instance is opened

Rather than doing nothing when a user attempts to open a second instance of the program, it's often beneficial to [Activate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.activate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the original window and change its window state to [WindowState.Normal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.windowstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which can provide an improved user experience if the original window was minimized.

To activate and make the window visible, modify the `SignalExternalCommandLineArgs` method as shown . (Note that [`MainWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a property of the `App` class, not to be confused with an arbitrarily-named `MainWindow.xaml.cs` class.)

```
public bool SignalExternalCommandLineArgs(IList<string> args)
{
    // Bring window to foreground
    if (this.MainWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
    {
        this.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }

    this.MainWindow.Activate();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: using this setup, how would you for example show, activate and unminimize the windows belonging to the app already running?

Comment: @Julien I just added an additional section to my answer called **Single Instance techniques** which answers this question. Short version: Call the `Activate()` method on the `MainWindow` property of `App`, and set its `WindowState` to `WindowState.Normal`.

Comment: @EvanWondrasek, I have tried your solution for a clickone wpf, which used WindowsFormApplictionBase before.However,both of the approach has same issue of not capture second/later  instances startup args. It only works for first instance and not for anything after. I have a separate post, which describe more about the issue. Any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463690/clickonce-not-passing-second-uri

Comment: This solution is great, if you want to add Microsoft source code that is not given under any license only declares "All Rights Reserved".

Comment: Updated version available here (with an Apache license): https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-7-Taskbar-Single-4120eafd (which the original blog owner referenced in this post: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/arik/2011/04/04/wpf-single-instance-application-update/).

Comment: Isn't it important for App.xaml's build action to be ApplicationDefinition? Can you comment on the implications of changing it?